# Clickable button inside of a table

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am writing a View of a composite list of employee information.  The view will display information such as first name, last name, job code etc...  My one problem is that I would like to have the boolean cells be clickable buttons.

For example: The HasHealthcare column will contain boolean values.

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th><label> FirstName</label></th>
<th><label> LastName</label></th>
<th><label> HasHealthcare</label></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
@for (int i=0; i < Model.Employees.Count; i++)
{
<tr>
<td>@Model.Employees[i].FirstName</td>
<td>@Model.Employees[i].LastName</td>
<td>@Model.Employees[i].HasHealthcare</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Table:

```
First Name | Last Name | Has Healthcare

Bob        |  Smith    | True
```

I would like "True" to be a clickable button so that if I click it the opposite boolean value appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to autosave at each click you could use Ajax and JQuery like below. And you would need a matching [HttPost] actionmethod as well.

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th><label> FirstName</label></th>
<th><label> LastName</label></th>
<th><label> HasHealthcare</label></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
@for (int i=0; i < Model.Employees.Count; i++)
{
<tr>
<td>@Model.Employees[i].FirstName</td>
<td>@Model.Employees[i].LastName</td>
<td><a class="healthcare" data-id="@Model.Employees[i].Id" href="#">@Model.Employees[i].HasHealthcare</a></td>
</tr>
}
</tbody>

<script>
$().ready(function(){
     $(".healthcare").click(function(){
      var element = this;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {isHealthcare:$(element).text().toLowerCase()==='true', id:$(this).data("id") },
        success: function(result){
           $(element).text(result);
        },
        dataType: "json"
     });
   });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Multiple elements with the same ID will be inconsistent across different browsers, and won't work correctly on any of them.  You should use a class name instead.

Comment: yes thanks, it should be class of course now changed.

Comment: This works like a charm, but the value displayed is either "true" or "false".  Do you know how I can turn "true" into "True"?

Comment: Thats strange, I thought the C# representation shold be True/False by default. This was the reason I used text().toLowerCase in the first place.

Otherwise something like:
char.ToUpper(@...HasHealthcare.ToString()[0]) + @...HasHealthcare.ToString().Substring(1);

Comment: If it reloads the page it'll show correctly.  The JQuery above doesn't require a full page reload though.  My posts returns a boolean to the JQuery.  Neither of those above work unfortunately.

Comment: You can do like this in the success response: var hc=obj.healthcare.toString(); obj.healthcare=hc.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + hc.slice(1)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using a checkbox, the following may work for you:

```
<table>
     <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><label> FirstName</label></th>
                <th><label> LastName</label></th>
                <th><label> HasHealthcare</label></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Employees.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Model.Employees[i].FirstName</td>
                <td>@Model.Employees[i].LastName</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Employees[i].HasHealthCare, false)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would agree with the recommending use of a `checkbox` instead of a `button` for something with this usability.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I think a checkbox would be much better and he can use CSS to make it look like a button if he wants to.